# Change dtype of dataframe columns with numpy

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy

I am fetching data from a sql table into a dataframe using connectorx library. Using connectorx results in byte string format I want to change it back to usual.

I am converting the dtype using following code and it is very slow. Is there a faster approach to convert dtype of dataframe columns? Can you suggest how to do this using numpy?

My code using iris dataset available online:

```
import pandas as pd
import connectorx as cx
import time

db_url="mysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost:{port}/{db}".format(user="cookie",pw="cookie123",db="mydb",port=3306)
query='Select * from test'
iris=cx.read_sql(db_url,query)

for col, dtype in iris.dtypes.items():
    if dtype == object:
        iris[col] = iris[col].str.decode('utf-8').fillna(iris[col])
    elif dtype == 'Int64':
        iris[col] = iris[col].astype('int64')
```

Comment: If the type is already int64, not need to change it again, otherwise I doubt you can be much more efficient

Comment: 'Int64' and 'int64' are not the same. My real dataset has much more data and its timetaking for that.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the capital `I`

Comment: When I use connectorx to extract data, I get strings not bytes. What is your SQL type for object column (and your SQL engine)?

Comment: I am using MySQL database. Dtype in SQL is **text** for object columns.  The values look like **b'setosa'** which is a bytestring.  The db_url for connectorx looks like this: db_url="mysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost:{port}/{db}" . I am not sure what the engine is.

Comment: Can you try modify your schema and replace TEXT by VARCHAR to get strings and not bytes?

Comment: @Corralien Yes that helped, Thank you very much. Also integer columns are **'Int64'** after fetch. do you have a suggestion for that? In SQL datatype is **int**

Answer (score 1):

For `object` columns, convert your schema from `TEXT` to `VARCHAR`. `connectorx` will return strings instead of bytes.

For `numeric` columns, unfortunately, you can't do anything but the downcast from `Int64` to `int64` should not have performance issue. `connectorx` uses explicitly `pd.Int64`. The difference between `Int64` and `int64` is essentially to allow null values without cast to `float64`.